# WS-Discovery Implementations for Java

Tags: java, web-services, ws-discovery

Are there any implementations of the WS-Discovery specification for JAX-WS RI, Axis2, CXF or other toolkits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only Java-implementation that I know of is this one: http://code.google.com/p/java-ws-discovery/

There are JAX-WS examples in the Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of the question CXF was not supporting WS-Discovery. It is supported since release 2.7 (http://cxf.apache.org/docs/27-migration-guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please check my lightweight approach JavaWsDiscovery: https://github.com/thhart/javaWsDiscovery. It will query the local network with a WS-Discovery probe and returns you all answering devices.